# VBScript array ? If then else

Tags: arrays, vbscript

I am new to VBScript and a solution we utilise has VBScript to manipulate data

Doing if then else is not a problem but when I have a large data set, with little output I am looking to use some kind array, can I store the values in an array and still utilise if then else

Very basic in requirement but after looking around seem to be getting a little muddled up on syntax

Simple if then else which is fine, but would have to write a lot of if then else

```
    If Input1 = "A1" Then
    Output0 = "A"

    ElseIf Input1 = "B1" Then
    Output0 = "B"

    Else
    Output0 = "C"
    End If
```

What I need to achieve is, please note values aren't the same and a trim wouldn't be the requirement from the below

```
If Input1 = "A1,A2,A3" Then
Output0 = "A"

ElseIf Input1 = "B1,B2,B3" Then
Output0 = "B"

Else
Output0 = "C"
End If
```

Using SQL I would do an `IN` statement

Comment: Have you looked at the Filter command, http://www.tutorialspoint.com/vbscript/vbscript_arrays.htm ?

Comment: @JBKing In terms of the example the OP has given `Filter()` would work but if the values varied not so much. For example `AB1` would return `Output0 = "A"` and `Output0 = "B"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For completeness, you can also use a [`Select Case`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6ef9w614(v=vs.84).aspx) statement, which allows an expression list in   a `Case` eg

```
Select Case Input1
    Case "A1", "A2", "A3"
        Output0 = "A"
    Case "B1", "B2", "B3"
        Output0 = "B"
    Case "C1", "C2", "C3"
        Output0 = "C"
    Case Else
        Output0 = "D"
End Select
```

Comment: Perfect other than ending with End Select not Case

Comment: Sorry about that, I should have tested it

Answer (score 3):

VBscript's tool to map inputs to outputs is the [Dictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x4k5wbx4%28v=vs.84%29.aspx). So use one as in:

```
>> Set d = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
>> d("A1") = "A"
>> d("A2") = "A"
>> d("B1") = "B"
>> d("C")  = "C"
>> For Each k In Split("C B1 A2 B2 A1")
>>     If d.Exists(k) Then
>>        WScript.Echo k, d(k)
>>     Else
>>        WScript.Echo k, "???"
>>     End If
>> Next
>>
C C
B1 B
A2 A
B2 ???
A1 A
```

Comment: Just out of interest, what do you use to generate your code samples?

Comment: My brain and a REPL based on http://www.visualbasicscript.com/WeeklyMonthly-Challenge-m47585-p2-print.aspx. Alternative: http://www.planetcobalt.net/sdb/vbsh.shtml

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, but this seems the same as doing a lot if then else statements, after a little more digging, I am going to take this kind of approach but I will build a sql table 1st then call that as an intermediate table for the data